# Patarin’s H-Coefficient Technique

Tags: pseudo-random-function, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I have come across many paper that applies Patarin’s H-Coefficient Technique in various cryptographic securities (KPA, CPA, CCA,...).

I am asking kindly if someone could explain it **simple with example** so i can absorb the method to apply it for different cryptographic primitives.